# Elasticsearch: field inserted with keyword mapping become string type

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

**Elasticsearch version: 5.6.5**

I am using Elasticsearch Python API to create indices and bulk-insert documents:

```
EVENT = {
    "mappings": {
        "my_mapping": {
            "properties": {
                "event_time": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "some_field": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

es = Elasticsearch("localhost")
es.indices.create(index="some_index", ignore=400, body=EVENT)
actions = [
            {
                '_index': index,
                '_type': "my_mapping",
                '_source': doc
            } for doc in a_list_of_dictionaries]
helpers.bulk(es, actions, raise_on_error=True, request_timeout=15)
```

However, the above code created a "some_field" field as `string` type instead of `keyword`, I also see a string field called "some_field.keyword" populated automatically.

How do I create a `keyword` field so that I can search for only exact whole word match?

Comment: `EVENT` vs `Event` maybe?

Comment: @Val Ah, thanks! Fixed.